SQL: Building multi-part SQL query (Replace, join, get counts)
I am working with a couple tables at my company that I am not the owner of. I cannot edit the data so an Update is out of the question. I want to Join the tables and then get counts of based on certain parameters. However, in order to Join the tables I need to modify a column in the one table so that this can be my linked column between the tables.
Basically Table 1 has the related column in this format: "AA:BB:CC:DD" and Table 2 has the data in this format: "AABBCCD". So I cannot Join them using the two columns. So, first I want to do something like this:
SELECT column1, REPLACE(column1, ":", "")
FROM table1

And then, in the same query, I want to do a join between Table 1 and 2 using the Replaced column to link them. I then want to filter that joined table to get the counts of various rows based on some parameters. Is it possible to do a multi-step query like this in SQL? See attached images for mockup of the tables I am using. Again here is what I want to do:
1.) Replace colons in MacID column of Table1 with blanks (to delete colons)
2.) Join Table 1 and Table 2. I want to keep all of Table 2. Then I want to link the meter_form and meter_class associated with a MacID to Table 2 and add two new columns to Table2 that are meter_form and meter_class. The result would be that for every row a given MacID shows up in Table2 the associated meter_form and meter_class would be linked to that MacID in the new columns. The MacIDs will show up thousands of times in Table 2. But the associated meter_form and meter_class will always be the same.
3.) I then want to count the number of rows in which the current column value exceeds the associated meter_class value. I want to display the counts by MacID.
See tables below:


Here is what I tried:

SELECT table1.meter_class, table1.meter_form, table2.MacID

FROM (
SELECT MacID, REPLACE(MacID, ":", "") as newmac
FROM table1)


RIGHT JOIN table1
ON table1.newmac = table2.MacID


Was hoping you could do multistep queries like the above but this doesn't work.  Got back the following error:
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 9:0 cannot recognize input near 'RIGHT' 'JOIN' 'coc1_ami' in subquery source

And here is how I would do the counts. Don't know how to link the above sections.:
SELECT count(MacID), MacID
FROM table2 
where current > meter_class
group by MacID,
having count(*) > 10


The derived table (FROM clause subquery) needs a name. Just before RIGHT. (Meant to be called table2?)

You can use CTE like below ,
Select A.MacID INTO #Table1 From 
(Select 'A:B:C' MacID Union all
Select 'X:Y:Z' MacID) A

Select * 
  Into #Table2 from
  (
  Select 12 'Current', 'ABC' MacID, 200 'Class' Union
  Select 50 'Current', 'XYZ' MacID, 320 'Class' Union
  Select 220 'Current', 'ABC' MacID, 200 'Class'   
  ) B
  
  ;With newTable1 as 
(Select MacID, REPLACE(MacID,':','') newMac from #Table1)

Select T2.MacID, Count(T2.MacID) TotalCount 
    from newTable1 T1 
    Right Join #Table2 T2 on T1.newMac = T2.MacID
    Where T2.[Current] > T2.Class
Group By T2.MacID 

FiddleQuery here
